# Координаты из OSM в GeoJSON

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Имеется файл с координатами OSM в формате GeoJSON. Объектов очень много (примерно 150000). Типы у объектов разные (Point, LineString, MultiPolygon). MultiPolygon преобразовал в Polygon. Объекты на карту наношу при помощи objectmanager. Point на карту наносится без проблем, а с Polygon проблема. Из 75000 рисуется 12!!!! Попробовал при помощи GeoObjectCollection отрисовать пару сотен полигонов. Отрисовались без проблем. Они же при помощи objectmanager не рисуются никак.
Помогите разобраться пожалуйста.

Comment: Соберите пример с вашими данными так, добавьте несколько объектов которые не рисуются: jsfiddle.net/86zsbmud

Answer (score 0):

Походу победил проблему. Оказалось, что при преобразовании Мультиполигона в Полигон неправильно считался id. Выявил (благодаря помощи se0ga), когда копировал свои полигоны на jsfiddle ))))))) 
Теперь 20000 полигонов со скрипом, но рисуются. И после жестоко тормозит браузер. 75000 не прорисовываются. Браузер просто зависает. Как я понял, это из за тяжести входного файла. (Причем это даже не весь город. А нужна будет страна (Казахстан)). Подскажите, как быть в таких случаях? Куда копать?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте LoadingObjectManager и динамически загружайте ваши полигони из сервера. Я вывожу 30 000 меток (постепенно конечно) на карту и нормально (метки отображаются только те которые попадают в viewport)

Comment: А можно подробней и пример желательно? Вы используете подход через тайлы или через видимую область карты?